# Is it possible to save a property type into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have to save information to SQL server and I know how to do it.

```
    Class LayoutProperty
        Public Property LayoutObject As Enums.LayoutObject ' SQL int
        Public Property Name As String = "" ' SQL Varchar
        Public Property GroupName As String = "" ' SQL Varchar
        Public Property Visible As Boolean = True ' SQL Int
        Public Property Enabled As Boolean = True ' SQL Int
        Public Property DisplayIndex As Integer = 0 ' SQL Int
        Public Property RefEnumType As Type = Nothing ' **SQL ?????**
    End Class
  
    Enum Language
        English = 0
        German = 1
    End Enum

    Enum LayoutObject
        TextBox = 0
        Label = 1
        DropDownList = 2
        ListBox = 3
        CheckBox = 4
    End Enum

Public Sub Test()
    Dim L As New LayoutProperty With {
            .DisplayIndex = 1,
            .Enabled = True,
            .GroupName = "ABC",
            .LayoutObject = LayoutObject.DropDownList,
            .Name = "Test",
            .Visible = True,
            .RefEnumType = GetType(Language)
        }
End Sub
```

The Question: Is it possible to save the Type (NOT the value) in SQL and if, which type of SQL variable.

I need the type to fill out ComboBox in a programmatically loaded form.

```
 Class EnumItem
    Property Value As Object = Nothing
    Property Text As String = ""
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Text
    End Function
End Class
Public Shared Sub EnumToDropDownList(DropDownList As Object, EnumType As Type)       
    For Each Itm In [Enum].GetValues(EnumType)
        If DropDownList.GetType = GetType(ComboBox) Then
            DropDownList.Items.Add(New EnumItem With {.Text = Itm.ToString, .Value = Itm})
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You can create user-defined data types in SQL server. What's not clear is what you are asking. You would have to define the data type in SQL server before using that data type to pass data back and forth between SQL server and .Net code. Research SQL custom data types: https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-user-defined-sql-server-types/

Answer (score 1):

> Type in SQL and if, which type of SQL variable

Enums are ints.  In SQL Server those int columns would typically be foreign keys to a table like

`create table Language(LanguageId int primary key, Name nvarchar(200))`

Comment: Is there any easy automatic way to keep the values in the SQL Server table synchronised with the enum declaration in the VB.NET code?

Comment: Look at EF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ or EF Core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/